# Haskell - Reproduce numpy's reshape

Tags: arrays, numpy, haskell

Getting into Haskell, I'm trying to reproduce something like [numpy's reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with lists. Specifically, given a flat list, reshape it into an n-dimensional list:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 18)
b = a.reshape([-1, 2, 3])

# b = 
# 
# array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6]],
# 
#        [[ 7,  8,  9],
#         [10, 11, 12]],
# 
#        [[13, 14, 15],
#         [16, 17, 18]]])
```

I was able to reproduce the behaviour with fixed indices, e.g.:

```haskell
*Main> reshape23 [1..18]
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]],[[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]]
```

My code is:

```haskell
takeWithRemainder :: (Integral n) => n -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
takeWithRemainder _ [] = ([], [])
takeWithRemainder 0 xs = ([], xs)
takeWithRemainder n (x:xs) = (x : taken, remaining)
                                where (taken, remaining) = takeWithRemainder (n-1) xs

chunks :: (Integral n) => n -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunks _ [] = []
chunks chunkSize xs = chunk : chunks chunkSize remainderOfList
                        where (chunk, remainderOfList) = takeWithRemainder chunkSize xs

reshape23 = chunks 2 . chunks 3
```

Now, I can't seem to find a way to generalise this to an arbitrary shape. My original idea was doing a fold:

```haskell
reshape :: (Integral n) => [n] -> [a] -> [b]
reshape ns list = foldr (\n acc -> (chunks n) . acc) id ns list
```

But, no matter how I go about it, I always get a type error from the compiler. From my understanding, the problem is that at some moment, the type for `acc` is inferred to be `id`'s i.e. `a -> a`, and it doesn't like the fact that the list of functions in the fold all have a different (although compatible for composition) type signature. I run into the same problem trying to implement this with recursion myself instead of a fold.
This confused me because originally I had intended for the `[b]` in `reshape`'s type signature to be a stand-in for "another, dissociated type" that could be anything from `[[a]]` to `[[[[[a]]]]]`.

How am I going wrong about this? Is there a way to actually achieve the behaviour I intended, or is it just plain wrong to want this kind of "dynamic" behaviour in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two details here that are qualitatively different from Python, ultimately stemming from dynamic vs. static typing.

**The first one** you have noticed yourself: at each chunking step the resulting type is different from the input type. This means you cannot use `foldr`, because it expects a function of one specific type. You could do it via recursion though.

**The second problem** is a bit less obvious: the return type of your `reshape` function depends on what the first argument is. Like, if the first argument is `[2]`, the return type is `[[a]]`, but if the first argument is `[2, 3]`, then the return type is `[[[a]]]`. In Haskell, all types must be known at compile time. And this means that your `reshape` function cannot take the first argument that is defined at runtime. In other words, the first argument must be at the type level.

Type-level values may be computed via type functions (aka "type families"), but because it's not *just* the type (i.e. you also have a value to compute), the natural (or the only?) mechanism for that is a type class.

So, first let's define our type class:

```
class Reshape (dimensions :: [Nat]) from to | dimensions from -> to where
    reshape :: from -> to
```

The class has three parameters: `dimensions` of kind `[Nat]` is a type-level array of numbers, representing the desired dimensions. `from` is the argument type, and `to` is the result type. Note that, even though it is known that the argument type is always `[a]`, we have to have it as a type variable here, because otherwise our class instances won't be able to correctly match the same `a` between argument and result.

Plus, the class has a functional dependency `dimensions from -> to` to indicate that if I know both `dimensions` and `from`, I can unambiguously determine `to`.

Next, the base case: when `dimentions` is an empty list, the function just degrades to `id`:

```
instance Reshape '[] [a] [a] where
    reshape = id
```

And now the meat: the recursive case.

```
instance (KnownNat n, Reshape tail [a] [b]) => Reshape (n:tail) [a] [[b]] where
    reshape = chunksOf n . reshape @tail
        where n = fromInteger . natVal $ Proxy @n
```

First it makes the recursive call `reshape @tail` to chunk out the previous dimension, and then it chunks out the result of that using the value of the current dimension as chunk size.

Note also that I'm using the [`chunksOf` function from the library `split`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.24/split-0.2.3.3/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf). No need to redefine it yourself.

Let's test it out:

```
λ reshape @ '[1] [1,2,3]          
[[1],[2],[3]]                     

λ reshape @ '[1,2] [1,2,3,4]        
[[[1,2]],[[3,4]]]                   

λ reshape @ '[2,3] [1..12]              
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]

λ reshape @ '[2,3,4] [1..24]                                                      
[[[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]],[[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24]]]]
```

---

For reference, here's the full program with all imports and extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, TypeApplications,
    ScopedTypeVariables, DataKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures,
    FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances,
    AllowAmbiguousTypes
#-}

import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import GHC.TypeLits (Nat, KnownNat, natVal)

class Reshape (dimensions :: [Nat]) from to | dimensions from -> to where
    reshape :: from -> to

instance Reshape '[] [a] [a] where
    reshape = id

instance (KnownNat n, Reshape tail [a] [b]) => Reshape (n:tail) [a] [[b]] where
    reshape = chunksOf n . reshape @tail
        where n = fromInteger . natVal $ Proxy @n
```

Comment: What is the `(..)` part in `import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))`?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann `(..)` means import all of data type constructors and possibly the record fields. Since `Proxy` has only one constructor it is equivalent to `Proxy(Proxy))`

Answer (score 7):

@Fyodor Soikin's answer is perfect with respect to the actual question. Except there is a bit of a problem with the question itself. Lists of lists is not the same thing as an array. It is a common misconception that Haskell doesn't have arrays and you are forced to deal with lists, which could not be further from the truth.

Because the question is tagged  with `array` and there is comparison to `numpy`,  I would like to add a proper answer that handles this situation for multidimensional arrays. There are a couple of array libraries in Haskell ecosystem, one of which is [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv)

A `reshape` like functionality from `numpy` can be achieved by [`resize'`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.25/massiv-0.4.5.0/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:resize-39-) function:

```hs
λ> 1 ... (18 :: Int)
Array D Seq (Sz1 18)
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ]
λ> resize' (Sz (3 :> 2 :. 3)) (1 ... (18 :: Int))
Array D Seq (Sz (3 :> 2 :. 3))
  [ [ [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    , [ 4, 5, 6 ]
    ]
  , [ [ 7, 8, 9 ]
    , [ 10, 11, 12 ]
    ]
  , [ [ 13, 14, 15 ]
    , [ 16, 17, 18 ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Note that here, just like in my answer, the dimensions argument is at the type level